# JSONTokener: A JSONObject text must begin with '{'

Tags: java, json

Hitting exception in my code below for using JSON on a URI

```
public static String processRestResponse(String language){
    URI uri = null;
    JSONTokener tokener = null;
    try {
        uri = new URI("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:Java");
        URL url = uri.toURL();
        InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
        tokener = new JSONTokener(inputStream.toString());
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(tokener);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Exception as follows...

```
org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1
at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:410)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:179)
at Assignment1.processRestResponse(Assignment1.java:48)
at Assignment1.main(Assignment1.java:108)
```

Is there an alternative approach i can take that would suit?

Comment: `inputStream.toString()` pretty sure that's not how you read from an `InputStream`.

Comment: InputStream toString won't give you correct response. Check on how to read from inputStream

Answer (score 1):

make sure you read the the InputStream correctly using the right charset, for example like this:

```
StringBuilder textBuilder = new StringBuilder();
try (Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())))) {
    int c = 0;
    while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
        textBuilder.append((char) c);
    }
}
```

afteron you can use it:

```
tokener = new JSONTokener(textBuilder.toString());
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(tokener);
```

Comment: For some reason ide says "cannot resolve symbol UTF8" when i try this

Comment: Which java version do you use?

Comment: and make sure to import the right Classes :) `java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets`

Comment: java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)   Ah wrong import yeah... import sun.nio.cs.StandardCharsets;

Comment: Although IDE does not recognise java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

Comment: what is your compiler compliance level? :)